# Homeomorphism between $S^1$ and $(- \pi, \pi]$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Take
$$ (-\pi, \pi] \ni t \mapsto e^{it} \in S^1 $$
and
$$ S^1 \ni z = e^{it} \mapsto t \in (-\pi, \pi]. $$

Is this a homeomorphism between $S^1$ and $(- \pi, \pi]$? I tried to consider every open set in both spaces and it looks to me their preimages are still open sets...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a homeomorphism. $S^1$ is compact but $(-\pi, \pi]$ is not. The map is continuous, but its inverse is not. The inverse makes a "jump" at $e^{i\pi}$.

Comment: And $(-\pi,\pi]$ has cut points, while $S^1$ does not.

Answer (score 3):

It is a continuous bijection, but not open. The set $\left(0,\pi\right]$ is open in $\left(-\pi,\pi\right]$ but its
image is not open in $S^{1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to see that this (or any other map) cannot be a homeomorphism is to note that, if $f:S^{1}\to\left(-\pi,\pi\right]$ were a homeomorphism, then $g:S^{1}\setminus \left\{x\right\}\to\left(-\pi,\pi\right]\setminus\left\{f\left(x\right)\right\}$ restricting $f$ to the circle minus the point would also be a homeomorphism. However, $S^{1}\setminus\left\{x\right\}$ is still connected, whereas $\left(-\pi,\pi\right]\setminus\left\{f\left(x\right)\right\}$ is not, so $g$ and, hence, $f$ are not homeomorphisms.